# JavaScript function - array of image and array of answer with input type

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I need to make a question game using random image array and its answer when the user input the correct answer.

```
   <! DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <title>
    Guess the CharToon 
</title>
<head>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\CSS\samp.css">      
    <div id="timer" style="padding: 1%;background-color: white;border-radius: 1%;color: black;font-size: 30;font-family: aero; position: absolute;top: 75%;left: 85%;"></div>




</head>
<body>

   <h1>From what movie this<br>&nbsp; place can be found?</h1>        
   <p id="count"></p>  
   <form>

    <img id="pic" class="jpg" src="Nigel Uno.png">

  <input type="text" id="anss" class="type1" value="" ></input>
<button class="type2" value="submit" onclick="sub()">Submit</button>
</form>
     <a class="back2" href="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\HTML\HARD3.html"><img src="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\IMAGES\MENU\back.png" width="150" height="150"></a>

   </body>
    <audio src="F:\ANGELA\MM1\CHARTOON\SOUNDS\Main.mp4" autoplay loop hidden>     </audio>
   </html>
```

This is my script:

```
        <script>
     var Imagearray = [];
     Imagearray[0] = "Nigel Uno.png";
    Imagearray[1] = "perry.jpg";
     Imagearray[2] = "BOOTS.jpg";
     Imagearray[3] = "SPONGEBOB.jpg";


var a= Math.floor(Math.random()* Imagearray.length);


var anw = [];
anw[0] = "nigel"; 
anw[1] = "perry"; 
anw[2] = "boots";
anw[3] = "sponge";  

var scor = 2;
  function sub()
{
var correct = 0; 
if (a == 0)
 {

var ans = document.getElementById('anss').value;
if (ans == anw[a] )
{

    a= Math.floor(Math.random() * Imagearray.length);
    document.getElementById("pic").src = Imagearray[a];
    document.getElementById("anss").value = "";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML= scor + "  " +"/5";
    correct == 1;
    scor++;

}
else
{
    if (correct == 0 )
    {
        hideass++;
     document.getElementById("anss").value = null;

    }
    if (ans == ""){
        hideass = 0;
    }


   }




   }

if (a == 1)
{

var ans = document.getElementById('anss').value;
if (ans == anw[a])
{

    a= Math.floor(Math.random() * Imagearray.length);
    document.getElementById("pic").src = Imagearray[a];
    document.getElementById("anss").value = "";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML= scor + "  " +"/5";
    correct = 1;
    scor++;


}
else
{
    if (correct == 0  )
    {
        hideass++;
        document.getElementById("anss").value = null;   
    }
    if (ans == ""){
        hideass = 0;
    }
    }



  }
if (a == 2)
{

var ans = document.getElementById('anss').value;
if (ans == anw[a])
{

    a= Math.floor(Math.random() * Imagearray.length);
    document.getElementById("pic").src = Imagearray[a];
    document.getElementById("anss").value = "";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML= scor + "  " +"/5";
    correct = 1;
    scor++;


}
else
{
    if (correct == 0 )
    {
        hideass++;
        document.getElementById("anss").value = null;   
    }
     if (ans == ""){
        hideass = 0;
    }
}


     }

     if (a == 3)
 {

var ans = document.getElementById('anss').value;
if (ans == anw[a])
{

    a= Math.floor(Math.random() * Imagearray.length);
    document.getElementById("pic").src = Imagearray[a];
    document.getElementById("anss").value = "";
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML= scor + "  " +"/5";
    correct = 1;
    scor++;


}
else
{
    if (correct == 0 )
    {
        hideass++;
        document.getElementById("anss").value = null;

    }
    if (ans == ""){
        hideass = 0;
    }
    }



  }

  if (Imagearray.length == 3)
 {
window.location.innerHTML = ClearEasy();
}


}

  window.onload = function timerx(){
  var sec = 30;
  setInterval(function(){
 if (pause == 0)
 {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec + " " + "Seconds" ;
 sec--;
 }
  if (sec < 0) {    
        sec = 0;
        window.location.assign("Times_up_Easy1.html");
   sec = 30;
  }
   },1000);
   }

 </script>
```

I've tried many ways but I still don't know. The main objective of the game is that the image is display with the input box where the user needs to answer it correctly and add a score and go to another random image. So I need to use a random image array and the array of answer of that image when the user input the right answer the score add 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't really said what your specific problem is (you should have, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help), I'll try to provide some help without actually solving the problem.

There are a number of issues with your code, including (but likely not limited to)

- submitting a form for each answer - this *reloads* the page and
  erases any state/progress information you have.
- a huge amount of redundant/repeated code.
- variable names that save you far less time in typing now, than longer ones
  will save you when you (or someone else) reviews the code in the future.
- separating related info into 2 arrays - without reading the code, it's not
  immediately clear (though one *can* guess) that they're related.
- a timer handler that appears to rely on a non-existent variable (`pause`)

Something else to consider, is your method of pausing the game - by setting a variable to true or false. This is perfectly fine and functional, however - it comes with the drawback of leaving the timer running, dutifully firing once per second. It also requires you to check the state of the flag each and every time the handler is called. If you keep the result of `SetInterval`, you can use it in a call to `ClearInterval` - this will stop the timer, pausing the game and reducing energy usage. Naturally, you'll have to add extra code to monkey-around with the timer, should you decide upon such an approach.

Here's some code that aims to address each of the issues above in the bullet list (I don't bother with adding and implementing the ability to pause):

```js
var currentAnswerIndex;
var currentScore=0;

var answerObjs =
[
 { answer: "nigel", file: "Nigel Uno.png"},
 { answer: "perry", file: "perry.jpg"},
 { answer: "boots", file: "boots.jpg"},
 { answer: "sponge", file: "spongebob.jpg"}
];

function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 randomizeQuestion();
 //initTimer(10);
}

function initTimer(secondsBeforeTimeout)
{
 var secondsRemaining = secondsBeforeTimeout;
 const msPerSecond = 1000;
 var timerId = setInterval(intervalHandler, 1*msPerSecond);

 function intervalHandler()
 {
  if (gameIsPaused == false)
  {
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = secondsRemaining + " " + "Seconds" ;
   secondsRemaining--;
  }
  if (secondsRemaining < 0) 
  {    
   window.location.assign("Times_up_Easy1.html");
  }
 }
}

function randomizeQuestion()
{
 currentAnswerIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * answerObjs.length );
 byId('questionPic').src = answerObjs[currentAnswerIndex].file;
 // for debugging purposes
 console.log( "Current answer is: " + answerObjs[currentAnswerIndex].answer );
}

function checkAnswer()
{
 var usersAnswer = byId('questionAnswer').value;
 if (answerObjs[currentAnswerIndex].answer == usersAnswer)
 {
  currentScore++;
  byId('currentScore').textContent = currentScore;
  randomizeQuestion();
 }
 else
 {
 }
 byId('questionAnswer').value = '';
}
```

```html
<h1>Which movie contains this location?</h1>
<img id='questionPic'/><br>
<input type='text' id='questionAnswer'/>
<button id='checkAnsBtn' onclick='checkAnswer();'>Check Answer</button>(<span id='currentScore'>0</span>/5)
```

Comment: You are a blessing! God bless you!

Comment: how can I stop the score and go to another set of question? without using html?

Comment: Well, you could consider (i.e make) the current set of questions (`answerObjs`) just another object in an array of `answerObjs`. You'd then have two options - (0) re-write all the code that access `.file` or `answer`, to allow for the fact that they are in an object that is part of an array (as is currently the case) that is itself an element in a larger array. or (1) when selecting the set of questions you'd like to use, you could copy that set into a variable called `answerObjs` (make sure you rename your array of array of objects something different) - this would avoid changing much.

Comment: As for the score, I guess you've just got to decide on the condition that causes it to be stopped (nuked?) - perhaps you'd do it after the number of attempts at a set of questions exceeded a set number - you may also change the set of questions then too. I'd consider putting such logic into a function, that was called at the end of `checkAnswer`, or perhaps, in response to the timer running out. Often, coding (surprisingly enough) is the easiest part - determine and settling on the functional and behavioural specification is the hardest. Once you know what you want, achieving it isn't so bad.

Comment: how can I add a function in every answer because when answer is wrong there would be a trivia and a retry button?

Comment: Can't the answer have many option like "SPONGE" , "sponge" ?

Comment: Yep, though I left a hint in the source-code for a different (easier, and less flexible) method. Let's think about it - you've got lowercase answers. The user may type in lowercase, uppercase or a mixture of the two. Sooo many options... So, what if you first convert the user's answer to lowercase before you compare it to the stored answer? Try this in the browser's console: `if ("this IS a StRiNg".toLowerCase() == "this is a string") alert("Ah-ha!");`

Comment: the timer function is not working. how can I display the timer function? I already have a css of timer but timer is not displayed. only the design but now with "0:15"

Comment: Dunno Jaela, can't see your screen, hdd or code. If the problem is with my code, I assume you noticed that in `onDocLoaded` I commented-out the call to start it. (for easier debugging) As such, all one need do is uncomment it. If that's been done, then perhaps there;s an error message in your console, which you can access with `Ctrl-Shift-I` (in Chrome, at least)

Comment: the timer is okay, but how can I have a specific function for every image? Because when the user is wrong there would be a another picture a trivia and a retry button. how can i do it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you. Could you explain what you're after in a little more detail?

Comment: this is my main objective :
having array of images with its answer
when the user input the wrong answer there will be a display of the correct answer.

Comment: Sample:
Pikachu is the image
User inputs Dora
 Dora is wrong so there will be a trivia for pikachu so that user may know that pikachu is the correct answer

          but because of  this
         var answerObjs =
[
 { answer: "bernie", file: "F:/ANGELA/MM1/CHARTOON/IMAGES/Mediumlevel/M3ZIG.jpg"},
]

        they have the same answer: , file: with no specifi like answer [0]
so i can't have a function like
              if (usersAnswer != answer[0])
       {
         then the image trivia appears with retry button that goes again to     the question
      }